# Turn off tooltip in openoffice while scrolling?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

When I scroll through an Openoffice.org Writer document I have a constant tooltip with page number and (when applicable) the bullet I might be hovering over.

It frequently obstructs the text and is rarely useful, can I just turn it off permanently? I've looked through the tons of options but haven't found anything to shut it off.

RHEL 5.5, openoffice.org3-3.2.0-9483 (package Vendor: OpenOffice.org).

Comment: The option for this is said to be added to OOo: https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=25945 I can't see it in LibreOffice though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tools | Options | OpenOffice.org | General | Tips

Comment: I'm so glad that there's an answer to this. It's been driving me mad! This answer also works for LibreOffice.

Comment: Having used it for a bit, it's rather a shame that it turns off all tooltips, not just the annoying ones!

Comment: Hell yeah! This was getting mighty annoying.

Answer (score 5):

you can turn off tips in Tools>Options>General

Then you also need to restore the "what is this?" button on your toolbar since all tooltips will be off and the button can give back that functionality when used. 
Go to tools>Customize>Toolbars and in Standard toolbar turn on the button [at the bottom of the list].

Comment: Well, to add after some time of setting it up, I still turn tooltips on and off via Options whenever I am trying to figure something out in Libreoffice/Openoffice.

Answer (score 1):

In a Mac version:
OpenOffice.org > Preferences > Openoffice.org > general > under 'help,' uncheck the tips box!